# Delete one slide from a Google Presentation using API

Tags: ruby, google-api, google-drive-api, google-slides, google-slides-api

How is it possible to delete a slide from a Google Presentation using Google API?

In https://developers.google.com/slides/samples/slides it is said: `The Slides API allows you to create, move, and delete slides`. However, I'm unable to find how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DeleteObjectRequest for tihs https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#DeleteObjectRequest
Pass your slide id to objectId.

Comment: Oh ok, I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In google app script you can do:

```
var presentation = SlidesApp.openById("23423423lksdjfsdlkfj");
var slides = presentation.getSlides();
slides[0].remove(); // Remove the first slide
```

You have to put the proper file id from the long part of the URL of the slide document.